# Matrix Solution

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

I have  matrix integral equation of the following form

${f^{'}(x)}_{1 \times 1}A_{3\times 3}=P_{3\times3} (1-x)+Q_{3 \times 3}x \tag 1$  .

All dimensions are indicated in equation itself. " ' " indicate derivative with respect x

**Data given**

1. $P,Q$ are constants,and non invertible
2. A is   a constant
3. $f(x)$ is a scalar function

**Question**

What is the expression for **$f(x)A \tag 2$**. Simple integration appears to me. But I am just confused with matrix notation. I am new to that. Asking for confirmation. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can integrate both sides just as if you had only numbers, so
$$
f(x)A=P(x-\frac12x^2)+\frac12Qx^2+C,
$$
where $C$ is a constant matrix.

A more generally applicable remark:
If you want to solve the scalar function $f$ from your equation, you can do it without worrying too much about matrices.
If $A$ is the zero matrix, then $f$ can be anything.
If $A$ is nonzero, there is a nonzero element $a_{ij}$ (perhaps $i=2$ and $j=1$).
Your equation is an equation of matrices, so each element must be equal on both sides.
Thus you get
$$
f'(x)=\frac{p_{ij}(1-x)+q_{ij}(x)}{a_{ij}}.
$$
This is a scalar equation and easy to solve.
If you want to find $f(x)A$, just multiply the so found solution $f$ by $A$.